# make custom CALayer subclass automatically redraw itself after being added to a super layer

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

I am subclassing `CALayer` and doing custom drawing in `drawInContext:` method.

The problem is I need to manually call `setNeedsDisplay:` after I add an instance of my subclass to a superlayer, something like:

```
MyCustomLayer *instance = [MyCustomLayer layer];
//do some configurations
[self.view.layer addSublayer:instance];
[layer setNeedsDisplay]; //required
```

or the drawing will not happen.

But when I use buit-in `CALayer` subclasses (`CATextLayer`, `CAShapeLayer` etc.), the call to `setNeedsDisplay:` is not needed after adding them to a super layer. Can I make my subclass behaves like those classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`displayIfNeeded`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/displayIfNeeded) on yourself within the `init` method, however better is to subclass [`needsDisplayForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CALayer/needsDisplayForKey:) and return `YES` for the `@"transform"` key, which would redraw when the bounds changes (i.e. when first added to the view).

Comment: Than you for your reply. I ended up using needsDisplayForKey: and checking for both "transform" and "bounds" keys. For me, calling displayIfNeeded or checking only "transform" key is not working for some edge cases.